# How to compile only changed/new files with Flex 4.6

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, compiler-optimization

I'm trying to optimize the overall compile time of several Flex projects. They're all using Flex 4.6. I'm also using the Flash Builder Plugin with Eclipse.

Thing is: the compilation is slow as hell. It can take like 5min on a machine without SSD.

One thing I noticed, is that the incremental build option is not working as intended -or how I thought it was supposed to work- ... according to this:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7ed3.html

... this option is enabled by default when using Flash Builder. It was supposed to inspect the changes to the bytecode, and only compile the changed and new files. But if I change just a small piece of code on a actionScript file that is inside a Flex Library Project, it will compile the whole structure of projects that are using this file. So if another project (the swf container project, for instance) is using it, it will generate all of the classes again, including the whole swf file.

Is this how it's supposed to work? How can I change the structure of related projects to avoid this recompilation all the time? Isn't this exactly what the incremental compile option should do by default?

Answer (score 0):

5 minutes is ridiculous… a few things to try:

1. try not copying assets to bin-debug - Project Properties -> Flex Compiler -> Compiler Options -> Copy non-embedded...
2. try importing the source paths
   instead of linking swc projects if you have a complicated project
   structure

Number 2. is most likely the reason you're seeing incremental compile not working correctly. If you change a low level swc it will cause a cascade recompile of all projects which occurs serially.